# Using Git with Android

Tags: android, git

I am not new to Android, however I am new to version control. I work in a startup and whatever we do over here is what we learn by ourselves. I want to streamline my and my teams work so that we do not waste time in merging code files and messing them up. I tried to search on the internet about Git but this whole thing is pretty confusing. I want some reference or a video tutorial as in how to master Git and use it in context of android. I want a beginners level tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: there is pulgin in elipse for git use that

Comment: Yes I have already done that, installed EGit plugin on my eclipse, also I installed git using terminal. But now what? How do I go on from here, I also initialized a git repository with git init command.

Comment: thats all u can sync ur project there

Comment: How? I am confused, is Git and Egit different? will it make copies of my project online? Or do I need to make a git shared folder on my local server?

Comment: there is option when u right click the project

Comment: The team option? okay let me check this. Ill be back shortly to bug you more! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using git in Android is not much different from using git anywhere else. Git is language/framework agnostic. If you are looking for a good gitignore file(the file that tells git what types of files shouldn't be added to the repo) for Android, you can check the one [I use](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu/blob/master/.gitignore).

Here is a great book to learn git:
[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book)

Here is an interactive course:
[Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/)

It helps in the beginning to have a good GUI client if you are not too keen on the command line. Here's a good one:
[Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

Git can be intimidating at first and there are a lot of concepts to master. There are no shortcuts and the many online "cheatsheets" will only leave you more confused. Be patient and learn it. The payoffs are worth it.

**P.S:** IDE plugins such as EGit are generally terrible, ugly and tend to get in the way more than actually help with development. It depends on your preferences but I would recommend going with the command line.

Comment: Plus one, I will check the links out one by one!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [online course](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) to quickly master Git, step by step. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](http://gitimmersion.com/) tutorial to learn how to use git (through the console/command line, not specific to Android). There are also some graphical git clients.